# Handling of Misspelled Tags

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, spelling

[image: "webbroswers" are awesome.]

Just a few days ago i "eradicated" [visibilty](/questions/tagged/visibilty) manually (i think there were only 8 questions). Can moderators do something about this sort of thing with the click of a button?

**Edit:** Just noticed some relevant questions, so i'd be more interested in the count threshold at which a retag-request should be filed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, if it will take less time to retag all the questions than it will to post a retag request here on Meta, go ahead and retag them.  Somewhere between 10 and 15, I'd guess.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed some and someone else did too.

Comment: That was probably me, just opened all questions in tabs and went through them.

Comment: @H.B.: Yep, teamwork :)

Comment: Oh.  Ummm... I didn't even click the link because I assumed they were already handled.  Thanks guys!  :)

Answer (score 2):

If the misspelled tag is being used in enough questions, you could ask here on meta to make the misspelled tag a synonym of the right tag, if you cannot suggest a synonym. With "enough questions," I mean a number enough of questions that users are not able to understand which of those tags is correct.

The page that describes the privilege of creating tag synonyms, reports the following text:

> ***When should I propose a tag synonym?***
>
> Whenever you see questions being repeatedly tagged with the wrong or incorrect tag -- or multiple tags that mean the same thing -- it's a good idea to propose a tag synonym. The goal is to save manual retagging work by making the retagging automatic for common tag mistakes.